# sums of divisors and modulo operator

Tags: c++

The problem consists of a function S(i) which sums all possible divisors of a certain number, so S(18)=1+2+3+6+9+18=39. given this we must calcualte the sum of S(i)%MOD for values of 1 to n. with n being up to 10^12.

Here I used the occurence of the divisors for each i (by using the formula occurence = q = floor(n/i). and the formula floor(n/q) to see the last number i that shares that occurence with another number. Lastly I use the arithmetic sum formula to sum all divisors that share the same occurence, and multiply them by q, moving the i value by the number of values skipped as we already now their occurence. My problem is that nearing very large numbers the code fails, providing a wrong answer and faioing the test.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int MOD = 1000000007;

int main() {
    long long n;
    cin >> n;

    long long ans = 0;
    long long q = 0;
 
    long long a = 0;
    long long s = 0;
    long long ultimo_i = 0;

   for (long long i=1;i<=n;) {
        q = static_cast<long long>(floor(n / i));
        ultimo_i = static_cast<long long>(floor(n) / q);
        a = (ultimo_i - i + 1);
        s = ((i+ultimo_i) * a) / 2;
        ans += (s * q);
        i += a;
    }
    
    ans %= MOD;

    cout << ans << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it with `n=18` as in your example? If you got the wrong answer, try printing each intermediate value to see if it matches with your expectations. Better yet, take this opportunity to learn how to use a debugger (gdb) and step through the code to inspect the values.

Comment: Note that if you need to perform modular arithmetic, usually you should use it for *every* calculation. That said, given the limit (n up to 10^12), you might want to look for another algorithm.

Comment: "Coding problems" requiring a `result mod x` are not supposed to be solved by brute force, but by using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). In fact, they are math problems, not really coding problems at all.

Comment: ive identified the problem. I must somehow calculate this: s = ((a*(ultimo_i+i))/2)%MOD

but the multiplication of a and the sum of numbers exceeds the long long limit so it wraps around the lower limit giving out negative results. Does anyone know hoy to apply modular arithmetic to that expression?

Answer (score 1):

The expected result can't be represented as a `long long`, it's far too big and in fact OP's code is supposed to output that result *modulo* 1,000,000,007.

To obtain the correct value, though, we should use [modular arithmetic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Basic_properties) at **each** sensible step of the calculation.

It basically means that you have to apply `% 1,000,000,007LL` at each value and intermediate result (after every sum or multiplication) that is going to outgrow the range of the used type.

Note that the particular value chosen for the modulo, other than beeing a prime is also small enough to be safely squared as a `long long` (but **too big** to be elevated to the power 3), but (in general) not as an `int` (like in OP's code), which is a 32-bit wide type in most systems, nowadays.

To calculate `/ 2`, we need to find the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of 2 with respect to the said modulus. In other words, we need to find *x* such that

```
2 ∙ *x* ≡ 1  (mod 1,000,000,007)
```

Instead of using one of the proper [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation), we could just observe that

```
(1,000,000,007 + 1) / 2 = 500'000'004   -->   2 ∙ 500'000'004 ≡ 1  (mod 1,000,000,007)
```

So that, to divide by 2, we just have to *multiply* by 500'000'004 and then take the modulo (`% 1,000,000,007`).

There's another issue in the posted code:

```
long long n;
long long q;
// ...

for (long long i=1;i<=n;) {
    q = static_cast<long long>(floor(n / i));
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
    
    // ...
}
```

There's no need to use [std::floor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor), which returns a `double`. That operation, `n / i`, is already an integer division, producing ⌊n/i⌋ with type `long long`. The conversion integral to floating-point to integral again is just wasteful.